# dictionary/list mapping for bokeh plotting glyphs

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

Am relatively new to python, and even naive in bokeh.
I have a dataframe that looks something like below:

```
DEPT CATEGORY  AMOUNT    
500  AB11      -100 
620  BF66      0
620  CD45      500
.........
.........
2311 AB11      250
```

I am looking to have a scatterplot in the form of circle glyhs where the size of the circle would be some function of amount.
The x and y axis need to be DEPT and CATEGORY.

The problem appears to be when:

1. Not all DEPTs have the same number of CATEGORY; leading to a possible mapping issue ?
2. Not all Amounts are >0, so the size may also be an issue. I would like to have the negative numbers to have circles filld with red, the others in blue or white.

3.If the Amounts are huge, I dont mind using a log of the number to bring it down to a reasonable scale/size.

What am currently trying to code is something like this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

x=[df['DEPT']]
y=[df['CATEGORY']]
plot = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
plot.circle(x=x, y=y, size=(df['AMOUNT']))

show(plot)


C:\log\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\models\sources.py:89: BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length
  lambda: warnings.warn("ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length", BokehUserWarning))

 C:\log\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\models\sources.py:89: BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length
  lambda: warnings.warn("ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length", BokehUserWarning))
```

Comment: Passing a tuple to size argument is correct? `size=(df['AMOUNT'])`

Comment: Will it not be possible to have varying sizes based on the magnitude/absolute value of the amounts ? Please advise, as am quite new to this stuff

Comment: can you try without `size` argument?

Comment: Just tried that..
the plot comes out blank...No error in the console tho

Comment: Does x and y need to int or float ? My x's and y's are essentially strings/categorical

Comment: It turns out that, Scatter from bokeh.charts is working fine

from bokeh.charts import Scatter, output_file, show
scatter = Scatter(df, x='DEPT', y='CATEGORY', marker='circle',
                  title="Auto MPG", xlabel="Miles Per Gallon",
                  ylabel="Horsepower")

Comment: great that you figured it out. You can post it as answer.

Comment: Not really a solution..
As i wanted to make use of bokeh.plotting and not bokeh.charts.
Besides, I still cannot make use of size of the circle to reflect the amount..